# What is the rule for multiple methods(?) on and object (i.e. num.to_s.chars.map{|x| x.to_i**2}.join.to_i)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the structural rule of something like this? I'm newer to programming and I don't know the technical term for the ".something's" (methods?).

But, in this example, there are 5 (to_s, chars, map, join, and to_i).

```
    num.to_s.chars.map{|x| x.to_i**2}.join.to_i
```

Basically, all I am wondering is, what is the structure to building these? I've tried doing some similar and have received errors. So, is there a specific order or structure to these? And is the correct term method?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does this have to do with [tag:ruby-on-rails]? What do you mean by "structure"? Also, "I have received errors" is not enough information for us to diagnose what is going on. Can you provide a [mre], including the expected inputs and outputs, error messages, warnings, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should first get fundamental of ruby language. Ruby is one of the easiest language to get hold on. Checkout https://try.ruby-lang.org and you will better understand following.

It's an expression where there is chain of methods being called on the result of each expression.

Assuming `num` is an `integer`, see the comment below

```rb
num
  .to_s         # to_s on any ruby object converts it to string
  .chars        # returns individual characters in string array
  .map { |x|    # iterates over each number character in array
    x.to_i**2   # and convert each character to integer and sqare it( ** is exponent operator) 
  } 
  .join         # map returns new array and join/conctenate each number 
  .to_i         # convert it back to integer
```

so if num is `123`, it returns `149` which essentially each number is squared.

You can try yourself by running this code one by one in irb

[image]

Comment: So, is there any particular or rules when calling multiple methods?

Comment: @nolyoi There is nothing special about calling multiple chained methods, except that is becomes unreadable after a certain number

Comment: @Eyeslandic got ya. thanks!

Comment: @Eyeslandic mentioned as long as it is readable, you can chain it. However there is one edge case where if any method raises error or returns `nil` in the chain, further execution of method chain will halt and would raise exception. There is a safe navigation operator `&` which can help to safely call next method on return object in case your encounter `nil`

Comment: @AmitPatel Good call!